Spaces dominated by a CW complex are homotopy equivalent to CW complexes
I’ll be referring to this post:  If Y dominates X and Y is a CW complex, then X has the homotopy type of a CW complex
I’ll repeat the question here: If $X$ is a space that is dominated by a CW complex $Y$, i.e there exists a map $i \colon X \to Y$ and $r \colon Y \to X$ such that $r \circ i \simeq \mathrm{id}_X$, then $X$ is itself homotopy equivalent to a CW complex.
The solution is essentially from Hatcher, where he uses mapping telescopes. However, he is using very “basic” theory to solve this. I was wondering whether there was a better solution to the problem, namely via CW approximation, Whitehead, whatsoever (just classical homotopy theory). Thanks in advance!

I don't believe this any "better" than the proof using mapping telescopes, but there certainly is a way to do it using CW-approximation. Indeed, pick a CW-approximation $f\colon X^{\prime}\rightarrow X$. Now, $Y$ is a CW-complex, hence $f$ induces a bijection $f_{\ast}\colon[Y,X^{\prime}]\rightarrow[Y,X]$, in particular there is a map $\tilde{g}\colon Y\rightarrow X^{\prime}$ s.t. $f\tilde{g}\simeq r$. Then, $g=\tilde{g}i$ is a homotopy inverse to $f$. For, $fg=f\tilde{g}i\simeq ri\simeq\mathrm{id}_X$ and, since $X^{\prime}$ is a CW-complex, $f$ induces a bijection $f_{\ast}\colon[X^{\prime},X^{\prime}]\rightarrow[X^{\prime},X]$, so $fgf\simeq\mathrm{id}_Xf=f\mathrm{id}_{X^{\prime}}$ implies$gf\simeq\mathrm{id}_{X^{\prime}}$.
